# Automatically bind event to a Dependency Properties Value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command

I am trying to set up a custom user control derived from the ToggleButton control.

I would like to set up two new commands, CheckedCommand and UncheckedCommand.

I have defined the commands as below, and am able to bind to them. And I am firing them via some internal events. It all works great.

However I would like to be able to have these commands disable the button as the usual command interface does with CanExecute. As I understand it I need to use the CanExecuteChanged event and set the IsEnabled Property in here. However when am I supposed to bind this event, I looked at using the `PropertyChangedCallback` event of the `DependancyProperty` but then how do I unsubscribe the from any previously bound command.

It all ends up looking a bit convoluted, am I missing something simple or is this just the way it is.

```
        [Description("Checked Command"), Category("Common Properties")]
        public ICommand CheckedCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CheckedCommandProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(CheckedCommandProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "CheckedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ToggleTextButton));
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your specific requirements but in general I wouldn't do it like this. WPF has been primarily designed to be data-driven, whereas here you're implementing event-driven notification. Events are the old-school WinForms way of doing things and they were added mainly to facilitate an easier transition from WinForms to the new data-bound architecture.

IMO a more "correct" solution here would be to expose a boolean dependency property i.e. basically the same thing as the "Checked" property in checkbox. Users of your control can then bind that one property to a boolean property in their view models whose setter will be called whenever the state changes. A second "Enabled" DP will allow both you and your user to control whether or not the control should be enabled, again similar to how it's implemented in Checkbox.

To ask an obvious question though if it's checkbox functionality you're after then why aren't you just templating checkbox? Do you really need a usercontrol for what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: My control is set up to use commands, which I thought was the WPF way of doing things, it is bound to commands on the model.

I just want to be able to have the command affect the IsEnabled state as the WPF provided command interface on button does.